How to forward an email with Apps Script, but with file extension validation?
We have label in Gmail Inbox, and all those messages within that label should be forwarded to external Application. I created a time-triggered script which sends all those messages, but the problem is that Inline Images get send too (signature images, header images from message etc.) - I only need to forward PDF files attached to the mail, not with extra inline images.
How can I get rid of those inline images being automatically forwarded too? I cannot use GmailApp.sendEmail() because i need to keep forwarded message in same thread.
Here is the code to forward message:
lastMessage.forward(forwardingAddress, {
from: fromAddress,
subject: subject,
htmlBody: "<br> Message sent to external app <br>",
});

I also tried passing attachments as argument to forward function - it look's like script completely ignores that argument and still passes "default" attachments.
I also tested that code, but it doesn't work properly too :/
https://github.com/Moonie8t7/apps_script_forward_email_message_without_inline/tree/main
Here is the result of code above: https://freeimage.host/i/scripttest.JvQVeef
Thank You in advance for all Your help!

Also discussed at Reddit. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

You might have to use another email client that allows you to make a copy of the original email message, edit it, and then forward the edited message as Gmail, the Google Apps Script Gmail service and the Gmail API don't have methods to do that.
I.E. you might use Outlook for Desktop and connect the Gmail account using IMAP. This way, the edited message could be uploaded to the Gmail account mailbox, and then you could use Google Apps Script to forward the edited email message.
